# HTML input required attribute not working when trying to Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, required

I came across this code from https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-save-form-data-in-a-text-file-using-javascript.htm which allows you to Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript however when i try to validate the form by inserting the html attribute 'required' it does not work? thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/exftm3b8/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    div {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    input[type=text], textarea, select {
        font: 17px Calibri;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    input[type=button]{ 
        font: 17px Calibri;
        width: auto;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 7px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    
    <!--Add few elements to the form-->

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" maxlength="10" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="selCountry">
            <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px">    
</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="bt" value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
    </div>

</div>
</body>
<script>
let saveFile = () => {
    
    // Get the data from each element on the form.
    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    
    // This variable stores all the data.
    let data = 
        '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Age: ' +age.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Message: ' + msg.value;
    
    // Convert the text to BLOB.
    const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
    const sFileName = 'formData.txt';      // The file to save the data.

    let newLink = document.createElement("a");
    newLink.download = sFileName;

    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
    }
    else {
        newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        newLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(newLink);
    }

    newLink.click(); 
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does what it's written to do. There's no logic in the code you've given which handles form validation or input checking.

To get you started, here's some simple logic which will prevent the Download from happening if any form fields are left blank.

```
// Get the data from each element on the form.
const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

// Here is the new code
// Don't download thefile if any fields have been left blank
if (
  !name.value ||
  !age.value ||
  !email.value ||
  !country.value ||
  !msg.value
) {
  return
}

// This variable stores all the data.
let data = 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much Isaac. I have managed to prompt an alert with your input. Any input as to how i can make the form inputs' required like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/1/

Comment: n.b i prompted the alert by adding this code   if (
  
  !name.value ||
  !age.value ||
  !email.value ||
  !country.value ||
  !msg.value
  
) { alert("Please Fill All Required Fields");
      return;
    }

Comment: Sure thing, here is a fiddle with the required inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/3pm5udk9/1/

Comment: Added some extra validation via html input attributes; number, email and url. Added an extra form element and made select option 'required' https://jsfiddle.net/urc9n40b/1/

Comment: n.b option to remove scroll on number input 'Enter your Age' in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urc9n40b/2/              by including  /* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */ input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {   -webkit-appearance: none;   margin: 0; }
/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {   -moz-appearance: textfield; }

Comment: Recieve a Syntax error at start of the script part of this code http://jsfiddle.net/exftm3b8/1/ when trying to implement. syntax error starts at "let saveFile = () => {" 


I have tried inserting the script in different parts of the source code with additional brackets and tried inserting the script in a seperate jquery file with document ready fuction but still getting syntax error?

Comment: I used this code instead from http://grass.4mg.com/ and it now works. I still get syntax error possibly bcos use an old version of dreamweaver CS6.